# Plot a graph in matplotlib with two different scales on one axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a graph with time data on X-Axis. My data has daily information, but I want to create something that has two different date scales on X-Axis.
I want to start it from 2005 and it goes to 2014, but after 2014, I want that, the data continues by months of 2015. Is this possible to do? If so: how can I create this kind of plot?

Thanks.

I provided an image below:

[image: Image of the expected plot]

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, just use the following pattern as I observed your X-axis values are already the same so it would just plot the other graph on the right

For a dataframe:

```
import numpy, matplotlib
data = numpy.array([45,63,83,91,101])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.date_range('2005-10-09', periods=5, freq='W'), columns=['events'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(numpy.arange(10,21,2), index=pd.date_range('2015-01-09', periods=6, freq='M'), columns=['events'])
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(df1.index, df1.events)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(df2.index, df2.events)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

You can change the parameters according to your convenience.